# Literal antonym to "Outspoken"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms, puns

I'm working on a humorous project in which one character is called the Outspoken Mime.

The adjective "outspoken" means the mime in question is "free, bold, or unreserved in speech."  On one side, this describes the mime as gregarious, talkative, and friendly — while visually implying the mime literally *speaks out*, making the character a walking oxymoron.

Is there an antonym to "outspoken" that could imply the opposite double meaning?  Something to suggest a different mime is shy or reclusive, while visually appearing to (redundantly) claim they do not talk?

Comment: Would [*soft-spoken*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/soft-spoken) work for you?

Comment: It isn't clear to me from the question whether your mime or mimes (which is it?) speak out loud or not, or what characteristics you want to emphasize.  Does “visually appearing” refer to how the word looks, or how a mime looks?  If the latter, which mime, if there's more than one?

Comment: The Speechless Orator? (or taciturn, mute, dumb, closemouthed, &c)

Comment: @jwpat7 Sorry for the confusion, I meant visual as in the visual pun when reading the word itself.  I was looking for an anytonym that shared a similar visual play on words.

Comment: There is no literal antonym to _outspoken_ because _outspoken_ has no literal sense. It does **not** mean _to speak out_ (_*He outspoke at the town meeting last night_); it's always metaphorical and means to behave in certain ways which may upset certain people by not acknowledging certain cultural values (**which** ways of behaving, **which** people, and **which** cultural values all vary from usage to usage), and it's always generic -- i.e, it refers to a character trait, not to a literal habit of speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler Correct, in this case I'm relying heavily on the play on words to convey the literal sense of "speak out."  Similar to using the phrase "hot and bothered" on someone who is anxious *while* they are literally hot and literally bothered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest *[taciturn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taciturn)*:

> : temperamentally disinclined to talk

or even *[closemouthed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closemouthed)*:

> : cautious in speaking : uncommunicative; also : secretive

Comment: I like *closemouthed*, in that it can serve as that oxymoronish double-pun that the O.P. seeks.

Comment: @J.R. precisely why I included it.  :)

Comment: Similarly, **tight-lipped**.

Comment: Chalk one up for "closemouthed," it almost has a feel of secrecy to it.  What *isn't* he saying...

Answer (score 2):

*[Reticent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reticent)*, “keeping one's thoughts and opinions to oneself; reserved or restrained” might be relevant.  Also *cagey*, in sense “uncommunicative; unwilling or hesitant to give information” and conceivably  *[prosy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosy)* or *[prosaic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosaic)*.

Comment: +1 for *reticent*, but I don't see what *prosy/prosaic* have to do with this question. By my lights, *prosy* isn't even a word anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers – *[Prosy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=prosy)* not a word?! You must have your lights turned off. :) Etymonline says “1814, from prose + -y”.  [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosy) says “Unpoetic (of speech or writing); dull and unimaginative” or
“Behaving in a dull way (of a person)”.  The question is somewhat ambiguous, but one may think of a dull mime as opposite to an interesting one.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly "shy or reclusive", you might find the wordplay involved in [mum](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mum#Etymology_3) or even [mummy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mummy) quite a good fit. The alliteration is a bonus :)

Answer (score 1):

The word you want is ["introverted"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/introverted), which has the additional benefit of beginning with "in", in direct contrast to the "out" of "outspoken".